# Change Wall Thickness Cesium

Tags: javascript, html, webgl, cesiumjs

I am working with Cesium and I am using the Cesium.WallGeometry and I would like to thicken my walls to make them more visible when viewed from a distance because at certain angles the wall disappears. The only thing I can seem to do is change the maximum and minimum heights to lengthen the wall but no way to widen it. Anyone know either an attribute function that I missed or a way to modify the cesium source to change this? I am working with the full b-29 version of Cesium right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Walls in Cesium have no thickness; if you would like to draw a thick wall you should be using either [Corridor](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=Corridor.html&label=Geometries) or [Polygon](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=Polygon%20Outline.html&label=Geometries) geometry.  There are several other types of geometry that may provide what you are looking for as well; those links have more.